# How to get the json array from the json object?

Tags: android, arrays, json

Hello every one I need your help for reading the **random named** array from the json object.

In this task client make the json object according to his requirements.

like

```
 {
    "tags":[ "demo 1","demo 2","demo 3","demo 4","demo 5","N" ] 
 }
```

I'm using **"N"**  for defining the unlimited numbers of items in one array.

Here in This code user use **tags** key to put json Array in json object.

User can also make *emphasized text*array as **Clients**

```
  {
        "Clients":[ "demo 1","demo 2","demo 3","demo 4","demo 5","N" ] 
  }
```

I know how to parse

```
JSONArray jsonMainArr = new JSONArray(String.valueOf(ObjectName.getJSONArray("Keyname")));
```

Now my Question is How to get Json Array if we Don't Know the **KeyName** like **tags** or **Clients**

Comment: Try @himanshu's answer. It's helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
JSONObject mainJsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
Iterator<?> keys = mainJsonObject.keys();
if (keys.hasNext()){
    String key = (String) keys.next();
    JSONArray jsonMainArr = mainJsonObject.getJSONArray(key);
}
```

In the above code I am getting the main `JsonObject` from the original `jsonString` and using the iterator getting the first key inside the object and using it to fetch the `JsonArray`.

Try this solution and let me know if you have any issue implementing the same.

Comment: great, have a nice day!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for without Key or tag..

```
try {

    JSONArray itemArray=new JSONArray(jsonString);
    for (int i = 0; i < itemArray.length(); i++) {
        String value = itemArray.getString(i);
        Log.e("json", value);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```