# How to separate two array by it's name

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am getting array in json

```
"sub": {
            "insert_id": [
                161,
                162,
                163,
                164
            ],
            "venue_id": [
                "21",
                "3",
                "5",
                "6"
            ]
        }
```

like this i am getting it into `$allid` php variable now i want `insert_id :[161,162,163,164] and venue_id :[21,3,5,6]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the json array from the json object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38769107/how-to-get-the-json-array-from-the-json-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `json_decode` first, then you can use the data in any way you need

Examples (Note: Not the cleanest way to do things):

```
/* Decode JSON */
$data = '{"sub":{"insert_id":[161,162,163,164],"venue_id":["21","3","5","6"]}}';
$subData = json_decode($data,true);



/* Just Loop Through Values */
foreach ($subData['sub']['insert_id'] as $sub){
    echo ("<li>$sub</li>");

}


/* Create New Json */
$insertIdJson = json_encode($subData['sub']['insert_id']);
$venueIdJson = json_encode($subData['sub']['venue_id']);
echo ("Insert IDs: $insertIdJson </br>");
echo ("Venue IDs :$venueIdJson </br>");


/* Create Array Of insert_id */
$insertIdArray = json_decode(json_encode($subData['sub']['insert_id']),true);   
$venueIdArray = json_decode(json_encode($subData['sub']['venue_id']),true); 

var_dump($insertIdArray);
echo("</br>");
var_dump($venueIdArray);
```

Comment: thanks, i got an idea thanks for your reply, will try and let you know

Answer (score 1):

Lets consider json response in $json_result variable

```
$json_result = "sub": {
                    "insert_id": [
                        161,
                        162,
                        163,
                        164
                    ],
                    "venue_id": [
                        "21",
                        "3",
                        "5",
                        "6"
                    ]
                }

$result = json_decode($json_result, true);
$insert_id = $result["sub"]["insert_id"];
$venue_id = $result["sub"]["venue_id"];

echo "insert_id";
print_r($insert_id);

echo "venue_id";
print_r($venue_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use this.

$jsonData = '{"sub":{"insert_id":[161,162,163,164],"venue_id":["21","3","5","6"]}}';
$json_result = json_decode($jsonData,true);

$insertId = $json_result["sub"]["insert_id"];
$venueId = $json_result["sub"]["venue_id"];

echo "<pre>";
print_r($insertId);
echo "<br>";
print_r($venueId);
```